# Creating a radial chart with a different color for each axis label

Tags: d3.js, label

Is it possible to create a d3.js radial chart with different colors for each axis label? I've tried doing it with the code below, but with no success:

```
.style(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < unhealthyArray.length; i++) {
        if ($.inArray(unhealthyArray[i], capitalMeta) != -1) {
             return "fill","red";
        }
        else {
            console.log("black ",capitalMeta);
            return "fill","black";
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that `.style` is called for each element, i.e. there is no need for you to put a loop in there. I think what you want is similar to

```
.style("fill", function(d) {
      if ($.inArray(d, capitalMeta) != -1) {
           return "red";
      } else {
           return "black";
      }
  });
```